# AJAX request to https php server from Firefox and Chrome extensions

Tags: ajax, https, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm working on extensions for Firefox and Chrome. The data used by my extensions is mostly generated from ajax requests. The type of data being returned is private, so it needs to be secure. My server supports https and the ajax calls are being sent to an https domain. Information is being sent back and forth, and the extensions are working correctly.

My questions are:

Do the extensions actually make secure connections with the server, or is this considered the same as cross domain posting, sending a request from a http page to a https page?

Am I putting my users' information at more risk during the transfers than if the user were to access the information directly from an https web page in the browser?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser absolutely makes a secure connection when you use HTTPS.  Certainly, a browser would never downgrade the security of your connection without telling you: it will either complete the request as written or it throw some sort of error if it is not possible.

Extensions for both Chrome and Firefox are permitted to make cross-domain AJAX requests.  In Chrome, you simply need to supply the protocol/name of the host as a permission in your `manifest.json`.  In Firefox, I think you may need to use `Components.classes` to get a cross-domain requester, as described in the MDN page for [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_XMLHttpRequest_from_JavaScript_modules_.2F_XPCOM.C2.A0components), but I'm not 100% sure about that. Just try doing a normal request and see if it succeeds; if not, use the `Components.classes` solution.

Comment: Sweet! As I mentioned, both extensions are communicating with the https server, so ajax is working fine. I did already try as http, and transactions failed, so that works, too. I was wondering if the connection is as secure as a web page visiting an https domain before letting my users enter private information. That seems to be true, based on your answer. Thanks for your help, I really needed that confirmation from someone.